# Objective C Memory Management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am quite new in Objective C and right now I am reading a book (Learning Objective C on the Mac 6th edition). I am at chapter 9th (Memory management) and I get stuck at an example.
They give you a Car, Tire and Engine class, Car class has 2 instance members, a pointer to Engine  and one for an array of 4 Tires. All of this classes have their Accessors methods (Getters and Setters) for instance variables. Then when they are explaining about what is the best Strategy on memory management (when releasing or retaining the retainCount for deallocation) for object ownership topic, they say the next statemets for the code in the image:
[image]

NOTE: `engine` shown in setEngine methods refers to one of the instances variables of Car´s class

Why the `engine` instance variable of the `car2` object is the same as the newEngine Argument ?

Comment: "On October 12, 2011, Xcode 4.2 was released concurrently with the release of iOS 5.0, and it included many more and improved features, such as storyboarding and automatic reference counting (ARC)."
That book seems really out of date. You should probably learn current version of Objective-C first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the engine instance variable of the `car2` object is the same as the `newEngine` Argument?

The question is what *would* happen if you called

```
[aCar setEngine: anEngine];
```

...at a time when `anEngine` is the *same object* that is *already* the `engine` of `aCar`.  Suppose you did that. Then the first thing that the implementation of `setEngine` does is release the existing `engine`. But if this object is *also* `newEngine`, then you have now accidentally released the incoming parameter before you had a chance to assign it to the ivar and retain it.

The lesson is that you need to retain the incoming parameter *first* and *then* release the existing `engine` — just in case they are the same object. Or, even better, *check to see* whether they are same object, as I advise in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management_of_instance_variables_non_arc

Having said all that, I strongly suggest you throw this book away. It is too old. *No one* write this kind of code any more. Nowadays we have ARC which does all this *automatically*, exactly so that you don't have to. In modern Objective-C, saying `retain` and `release` is actually *illegal*. So you are learning about something you will never actually do, which is silly. You are learning a dead language. That's fun but not useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for you advice it is just that I am about to do some project (a framework ) for IOS 8 (or later) and I was asked to do it with this specific languaje instead of swift. ARC is already supported by Objective C ?,  do you know about some refereces that could help me with Objective C?, I really would appretiate it.

Comment: "You are learning a dead language." - that sounds a little bit too drastic.